# CXF Error: input message must reference global element declaration with same localnameas operation

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java

While running wsdl2java I was getting below message:

I am using cxf 3.1 with jdk 7
my wsdl2java command is as below

```
wsdl2java -d C:\esub\.cxftmp/src -classdir C:\esub\build\classes -p http://www.example.org/ESBProxy/=org.example.esbproxy -impl  -exsh false -dns true -dex true -wsdlLocation file:/C:/esub/WebContent/WSDL/ESBProxy.wsdl -verbose -sn ESBProxy -defaultValues -fe jaxws -db jaxb -wv 1.1 file:/C:/esub/WebContent/WSDL/ESBProxy.wsdl
```

output :

```
INFO: Operation {http://www.example.org/ESBProxy/}PublishOnESB cannot be unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same localnameas operation.
```

below is my wsdl

```
<wsdl:portType name="ESBProxyPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="PublishOnESB">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:NotifyRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:NotifyResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ESBProxySOAPBinding" type="tns:ESBProxyPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="PublishOnESB" >
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/ESBProxy/PublishOnESB" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ESBProxy">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:ESBProxySOAPBinding" name="ESBProxyPort">
        <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```